Limit $\mathbb E[|(\text{Poi}(\mu)-\mu)/\sqrt{\mu}|^{k}]\, /\,\mathbb E[|\text{N}(0,1)|^{k}]$ as $\mu=k^{3}$ and $k\to\infty$
Consider a Poisson random variable $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$ and a standard normal random variable $Y \sim \text{N}(0,1)$. We're interested in comparing their normalized moments.
For any positive integer $k$, define:

The normalized $k$-th moment for the Poisson: $M_k = \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu}}\right|^k\right]$
The $k$-th moment for the standard normal: $Z_k = \mathbb{E}[|Y|^k]$

By the Central Limit Theorem, we know that $M_k/Z_k \to 1$ as $\mu \to \infty$ for fixed $k$.
However, the behavior becomes more interesting when $k$ grows with $\mu$. Specifically:

When $\mu = \omega(k^{3})$, the ratio $M_k/Z_k \to 1$
When $\mu = O(k^{3})$, the ratio $M_k/Z_k$ remains bounded
When $\mu = o(k^{3})$, the ratio $M_k/Z_k\to \infty$

My question focuses on the critical case where $\mu = c k^{3}$ for some constant $c > 0$:

What is $\lim_{k \to \infty} M_k/Z_k$ as a function of $c$?
Is there a general methodology that could extend to other distributions beyond the Poisson case?


Update: Here is some numerical evidence from Mathemtica:


Let $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$ and $Y \sim \text{N}(0,1)$. Define:
$$
Z := \frac{X-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu}}, \quad
Z_k := \mathbb{E}[|Z|^k], \quad Y_k := \mathbb{E}[|Y|^k].
$$
We will show that, when $\mu$ and $k$ are linked by $\mu = c k^3$ for some $c > 0$,
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{Z_k}{Y_k} = \cosh\left(\frac{1}{6\sqrt{c}}\right).
$$
For $c=1$, we get $1.013921\dots$ matching the numerical evidence.
Edgeworth expansion:
We will use the characteristic function of $Z$ and its logarithm:
$$
\phi(t) := \mathbb{E}[e^{itZ}], \quad K(t) = \log \phi(t).
$$
For a standard normal random variable $Y$, we have:
$$
\phi_Y(t) = e^{-t^2/2}, \quad K_Y(t) = -\frac{t^2}{2}.
$$
For a normalized random variable like $Z$, we get:
$$
K(t) = \log \phi(t) = -\frac{t^2}{2} + \kappa_3 \frac{(it)^3}{3!} + \kappa_4 \frac{(it)^4}{4!} + \cdots
$$
Here, $\kappa_j$ are the (standardized) cumulants of the distribution. For $Z$ the cumulants are $\kappa_j = \mu^{1-j/2}$.
We can expand $\phi(t)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\phi(t) &= \exp(K(t))
\\&= \exp(-t^2/2) \exp(\kappa_3 \tfrac{(it)^3}{3!} + \kappa_4 \tfrac{(it)^4}{4!} + \cdots)
\\&= \exp(-t^2/2)(1 + \kappa_3 (i t)^3/3! + \kappa_4 (i t)^4/4! 
+ \kappa_5 (i t)^5/5! 
+ \kappa_3^2 (it)^6/72 + \kappa_6 (it)^6/6! + \dots)
\\&= \exp(-t^2/2)\sum_{j,\ell} c_{j,\ell} \kappa_j^\ell (i t)^{j\ell}/ (j\ell)!
\end{align}
To recover the probability density (or mass) function from $\phi(t)$, one uses the inverse Fourier transform:
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t) e^{-itx} \, dt.
$$
The Hermite polynomials, $H_n(x)$ are defined as the inverse fourier transform of $(it)^n$:
$$
H_n(x)e^{-x^2/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-itx} (it)^n e^{-t^2/2} \, dt.
$$
For example $H_4(x) = x^4-6x^2+3$.
(Also known as the Probabilist's Hermite polynomials.)
We can thus plug our expansion of $\phi(t)$ the inverse Fourier transform to get the Edgeworth-like expansion of the probability density:
$$
p(x) = \sum_{j,\ell} c_{j,\ell} \kappa_j^\ell \frac{  H_{j\ell}(x)}{(j\ell)!} \Phi(x),
$$
where $H_i(x)$ are Hermite polynomials and $\Phi(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ is the standard normal density. These expansions express $p(x)$ as a perturbed Gaussian density with corrections involving Hermite polynomials and powers of the cumulants.
Moment Calculation via Hermite Expansion
We now write the moments $E[|Z|^k]$ as an integral, and plug in the Hermite expansion:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|Z|^k]
&= \int |x|^k p(x) \, dx
\\&=
\int |x|^k
\sum_{j,\ell}
\frac{c_{j,\ell} \kappa_j^\ell}{(j\ell)!}
  H_{j\ell}(x) \Phi(x)
\,dx
\\&=
\sum_{j,\ell}  \frac{ c_{j,\ell}\kappa_j^\ell  }{(j\ell)!}\, \mathbb{E}[|Y|^k H_{j\ell}(Y)].
\\&=
\sum_{j,\ell}  \frac{ c_{j,\ell}\kappa_j^\ell  }{(j\ell)!}\, \mathbb{E}[|Y|^k (Y^{j\ell} + \dots)].
\end{align}
Now, recall that $\kappa_j = \mu^{1-j/2}$ and $E[|Y|^k]\sim (k/e)^{k/2}$.
Thus for $\mu=ck^3$, we get
$$
\kappa_j^\ell E[|Y|^{k+j\ell}]/E[|Y|^{k}]
\sim k^{3\ell-3\ell j/2} (k+j\ell)^{(k+j\ell)/2} / k^{k/2} \to 0
$$
unless
$3\ell -3\ell j/2 + (k+j\ell)/2 - k/2 = 3\ell - \ell j \ge 0$.
Since all $\kappa_j=0$ for $j < 3$, we can thus restrict to terms where $j=3$.
We can also ignore all terms in the Hermite polynomial except the largest one.
Finally, we can ignore terms where $j\ell$ are odd, since $Y$ is symmetric and so $E[|Y|^k Y^{j\ell}] = 0$.
Hence we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|Z|^k]
&=
\sum_{\ell \text{ even}} \frac{c_{3,\ell}}{3!} \kappa_3^\ell \,\mathbb{E}[|Y|^{k+3\ell}](1 + o(1))
\\&=
\mathbb{E}\left[|Y|^k
(\sum_{\ell\text{ even}} c_{3,\ell} \kappa_3^\ell Y^{3\ell}/3!)
\right] (1 + o(1))
\\&=
\mathbb{E}\left[|Y|^k
\left(
\exp(\kappa_3 Y^{3}/3!)
+\exp(-\kappa_3 Y^{3}/3!)
\right)/2
\right](1 + o(1))
\\&=
\mathbb{E}\left[|Y|^k
\cosh(\kappa_3 Y^{3}/3!)
\right](1 + o(1)).
\end{align}
We used that $c_3$ comes exactly from the original expansion of $\exp(\kappa_3 (it)^3/3!)$,
and the two exponentials with alternating signs cancels the odd terms.
Asymptotic Dominance and Limit
To compare $Z_k$ with $Y_k = \mathbb{E}[|Y|^k]$, consider the growth of $|Y|^k$. For large $k$, the main contribution to $\mathbb{E}[|Y|^k]$ comes from values of $Y$ around $|Y| \approx \sqrt{k}$. This is because $|Y|^k$ grows rapidly, and the Gaussian density $e^{-Y^2/2}$ decays. The product $|Y|^k e^{-Y^2/2}$ is maximized near $Y = \pm \sqrt{k}$.
Set $Y = \sqrt{k} + \frac{z}{\sqrt{k}}$. This change of variables zooms in on the peak region. In this scaling:
$$
Y^3 = (\sqrt{k} + z/\sqrt{k})^3 = k^{3/2} + 3\sqrt{k}z + O(z^2/\sqrt{k}).
$$
Dividing by $k^{3/2}$:
$$
\frac{Y^3}{k^{3/2}} = 1 + \frac{3z}{k} + O\left(\frac{z^2}{k^{3/2}}\right).
$$
As $k \to \infty$, terms like $3z/k$ and $z^2/k^{3/2}$ go to zero, so:
$$
\frac{Y^3}{k^{3/2}} \to 1.
$$
Therefore:
$$
\frac{Y^3}{6\sqrt{c} k^{3/2}} \to \frac{1}{6\sqrt{c}}
$$
as $k \to \infty$. This convergence is uniform in the region where the integral is dominated, because $z$ is effectively $O(1)$ in the scaling regime that matters.
Hence, inside the expectation defining $Z_k$, the factor $\cosh\left(\frac{Y^3}{6\sqrt{c} k^{3/2}}\right)$ converges to $\cosh\left(\frac{1}{6\sqrt{c}}\right)$ for the $Y$ values that dominate the integral.
Since $\cosh(x)$ is continuous and bounded by an exponential function, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to interchange the limit and expectation:
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{Z_k}{Y_k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[|Y|^k \cosh(Y^3/(6\sqrt{c}k^{3/2}))]}{\mathbb{E}[|Y|^k]} = \cosh\left(\frac{1}{6\sqrt{c}}\right).
$$

The moment generating function for $W=\frac{X}{\mu}-1$ is given by
\begin{align}
m(t)&:=\mathbb E e^{tW}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\mathbb E[W^m]}{m!}t^m
=\exp\left(-\mu - t + \mu e^{\frac t\mu}\right)
\\ &
=\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2\mu} + \frac{t^3}{6\mu^2} + \frac{t^4}{24\mu^3} + \dots\right)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m(\mu) t^m
\end{align}
and $M_{2k}=\mathbb E[W^{2k}]=a_{2k}(\mu)\times (2k)!$, $k=1,2,\dots$.
It looks that for $\mu=k$ we have $\mathbb E[W^{2k}]\uparrow+\infty$ whilst for
for $\mu=k^{1+\epsilon}$ (where $\epsilon>0$) we have $\mathbb E[W^{2k}]\downarrow 0$.
At the same time, by a well-known formula $\mathbb E Y^{2k}=\frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}\sim (2k/e)^k\uparrow \infty$, so for $\mu=ck^{3/2}$ this ratio definitely goes to zero.

I'm sorry, I meant $(\text{Poi}(\mu)-\mu)/\sqrt{mu}$. I messed up the variance vs stdev.
